# How to convert this Array to Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, type-conversion

I can't seem to find the answer, how to change array in array to object in array ..??

problem this in javaScript. How to convert? How to convert?

I have this array.

```
   [
    "or",
    [
       "or",
       {
           "status": 1
       },
       {
        "verified": 1
       }
    ],
    [
       "and",
       {
           "social_account": 1
       },
       {
           "enable_social": 1
       }
   ]
]
```

I want this object:

```
{
   "or": [
       {
        "or": [
            {
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "verified": 1
            }
        ]
       },
       {
        "and": [
            {
                "social_account": 1
            },
            {
                "enable_social": 1
            }
        ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: No attempt at all?

Comment: much but no result.

Comment: Share them then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function. The base case is when the argument is not an array. In the other case, extract the first array value as key for the object, and map the rest of the array via the recursive function:

```js
const convert = data => Array.isArray(data) && ["or","and"].includes(data[0])
        ? { [data[0]]: data.slice(1).map(convert) }
        : data;

// demo:
let data = ["or",
    ["or", {"status": 1}, {"verified": 1}],
    ["and",{"social_account": 1}, {"enable_social": 1}]
];

console.log(convert(data));
```

Comment: Please try this json data. We need recursive function.

"["or",["or",["or",{"status":1},{"verified":1}],[{"social_account":1},{"enable_social":1}]],[{"social_account":1},{"enable_social":1}]]"

Comment: That last subarray has no "or", or "and"... is that intended? Anyway I added a check in my code that it only recurs when the first array element is "or" or "and".